# ggplot non-alphabetical order using facet_wrap

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-wrap

is there any possibility to Change the order of facet_wrap? the normal order is alphabetical.

[image]

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=int, y=amino))+
geom_boxplot(aes(fill=CO2))+
labs(title="Aminosäuren Erdkultur",x="Genotyp", y="Aminosäurekonz.   [µmol/gFW]")+
guides(fill=guide_legend(title="CO2-Behandlung"))+
theme(plot.title = element_text(face="bold",size="17",hjust="0.5")) +
scale_fill_manual(values=c("violetred3","steelblue1"))+
facet_wrap(~n)
theme(legend.title = element_text(face="bold"))
```